# How do you correct this sentence to a right one?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms, american-english

I want to travel to Tokyo. If you go, let's travel with Kamakura!

-> I want to travel to Tokyo. If you are traveling, let’s do it with Kamakura?

can someone help?

i corrected the original sentence because the verb ‘go’ was a bit vague and not clear as to who is going where. but now i realize it is specified prior to. however let’s travel with Kamakura seems like it’s  entirely new sentence that’s not connected to the matters of the previous sentences.

Comment: There is nothing about the original sentence that needs to be corrected. It actually sounds better than the revision.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, I'll ignore the question mark at the end of the second sentence...

Both sentences technically have the same meaning, though the original is a 'cleaner' because it conveys the meaning in fewer words/syllables.

However, because the second sentence has a question mark, the meaning of it actually changes. This time, the speaker is questioning if it is okay that Kamakura travels with them. In the original sentence, it was a suggestion.

EDIT: tldr; the original sentence was fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think a more extensive rewrite is in order. Something along the following lines.

Are you travelling to Tokyo? If so, let's both go with Kamakura, since I want to also.